# Неправильная арифметика с переменной, полученной рекурсивно

Tags: bash

Имеется скрипт, в котором функция `traverse` выводит число листьев на дереве каталогов, корень передается в скрипт как параметр:

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSED=$1;

traverse(){

  DIRS=0;
  LOCAL_DIRS=0;

  for entry in "$PASSED"/*
  do
    if [[ -d $entry ]]; then
      LOCAL_DIRS=$((LOCAL_DIRS+1));
      DIRS=$((DIRS+$(./count.sh $entry)));
    fi
  done

  if [[ $LOCAL_DIRS = "0" ]]; then
    DIRS=1;
  fi

  echo $DIRS;
}

#Проблема тут
res=$(traverse)
let "res += 1";
echo $((res));
```

Для дерева каталогов с 20 листьями код

```
res=$(traverse)
echo $((res));
```

работает правильно и выводит `20`, однако

```
res=$(traverse)
let "res += 1";
echo $((res));
```

выводит `44`, а нужно `21`,

```
res=$(traverse)
let "res*= 3";
echo $((res));
```

выводит `540`, а нужно `60`.

Почему так происходит и как реализовать ожидаемое поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке с рекурсивным вызовом функции нужно было вызвать функцию, а не скрипт целиком:

```
 DIRS=$((DIRS+$(traverse $entry)));
```

и сооветственно добавить в функцию параметр, указывающий корень дерева:

```
...
__PASSED=$1;

for entry in "$__PASSED"/*
...
```

и тогда в конце вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
res=$(traverse $PASSED);
let "res *= 3";
echo $res;
```